# Creating a looping palindrome program for Java that wont close after input/output

Tags: java

I'm currently enrolled in a java course at college, and my project is to create a Palindrome program that inputs a string and outputs if the string is palindromic or not, but the program cannot close after doing so, as my professor wants me to input multiple strings by keyboard. Here is the beginning code:

```java
    // CSCI 200 Program 2

    import java.util.*;

    public class Program2
    {
      //
      // method: isPalindrome
      // pre-conditions: a string is passed in
      // post-conditions: return true if the string is a palindrome otherwise return false
      //

      public static Boolean isPalindrome(String s)
      {
        //Palindrome Code -- this requires a return statement, but i'm not sure 
        //what.
      }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("String: ");
      String word = s.nextLine();
      //
      // keep reading words until the word QUIT is read in
      //
      while (!word.equals("QUIT"))
      {
        //
        // call the isPalindrome method passing it the word
        // based on what this method returns (true or false) output a message
        //
        if (isPalindrome(word))
            System.out.println("the string [" + word + "] IS a palindrome.");
        else
            System.out.println("the string [" + word + "] IS NOT a palindrome.");
        word = s.nextLine();
      }
    }
  }
```

Under the method `isPalindrome`, it says it requires a return statement, but I'm not sure what it is, and I've been scratching my head for over two days trying different code and return statements. Any help would be appreciated.

I've also made a working Palindrome program by myself, but I can't seem to get it to repeat, it just takes one string (radar for example), says its a palindrome, then exits.

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't isPalindrome return a Boolean rather than a Boolean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type of `isPalindrome` method is `Boolean` that's why it requires a return statement of type `Boolean` either `true` or `false`. So if the reverse of a given string string is equal to   it's value then return `true` else return `false`. Below is working snippet:

```
public class Program2{

    public static Boolean isPalindrome(String string) {
        if (null == string)
            return false;
        String reverse = new StringBuffer(string).reverse().toString();
        if (string.equals(reverse))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("String: ");
        String word = s.nextLine();
        while (!word.equals("QUIT")) {
            if (isPalindrome(word)) {
                System.out.println("The string [" + word + "] IS a palindrome.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("The string [" + word + "] IS NOT a palindrome.");
            }
            System.out.println("String: ");
            word = s.nextLine();
        }
        s.close();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
String: 
test
The string [test] IS NOT a palindrome.
String: 
madam
The string [madam] IS a palindrome.
String: 
QUIT
```

Comment: This helped me understand so much, Thanks so much for this! Is there a way to ignore spaces in a string to check if it is a palindrome, for example: the string "a nut for a jar of tuna" would ignore the spaces and output that it is a palindrome? My professor said I can use String methods to do so, but can't find the ones needed in my book.

Answer (score 0):

I made a class before that checks for palindrome words see if this helps

```
class reverse
{
private String tmp="";
private int i; 
private boolean loop = true;
public void reverseMe(String msg)
{
if(msg.equals("xxx"))
{
    loop = false;
}
else
{
    i = msg.length()-1;
    do
    {
    tmp += msg.charAt(i);
    i--;
    }while(i>=0);

    if(tmp.equals(msg))
    {
    System.out.println("Palindrome");
    //loop = true;
    tmp = "";
    }
    else
    {
    System.out.println("Not a Palindrome!");
    //loop = true;
    tmp = "";
    }
}   
}
public boolean getLoop()
{
    return loop;
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add implementation for `isPalindrome` method, below is implementation for same-

```
public static Boolean isPalindrome(String s) {

    int leftCount = 0;
    int rightCount = s.length() - 1;
    int lenght = (s.length() - 1) / 2;
    boolean isPalindrome = true;

    while(leftCount < lenght ) {
        if(s.charAt(leftCount++) != s.charAt(rightCount--)) {
            isPalindrome = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return isPalindrome;
}
```

I would suggest, go through Java basic tutorial first then try to solve logical questions and also try to implement your own logic for `isPalindrome` method, maybe your solution will be better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

The return type in isPalindrome is Boolean which specify whether given input is palindrome or not.

you Can have reference from this program:

```html
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Pallindrome {
 private static String QUIT="QUIT";

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  String data = reader.readLine();
  
  while(!QUIT.equalsIgnoreCase(data)) {
   System.out.println("Input: "+data+" Pallindrome: "+isPalindrome(data));
   data = reader.readLine();
   
  }
 }
 
  public static Boolean isPalindrome(String s)
   {
     for(int i =0; i<s.length()/2;i++) {
      if(s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(s.length()-1-i)) {
       return false;
      }
     }
     return true;
   }

}
```